# How to add events in FullCalendar using an array retrieved from a mysql server (phpmyAdmin)?

Tags: php, fullcalendar

I am grateful in advance of any help I receive on this. I also apologise if my error is obvious. My problem is I can't seem to find an idea on how to display all the elements of my array to populate my events.

```
        for(var i = 0;i < count;i++)
        {
            // these are the arrays that contain my events
            var primaryAsset = primaryAssets[i];
            var release_Date = releaseDates[i];


            $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            header: {
                left: 'prev,next today',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
            },
            editable: true,
            weekMode: 'liquid',
            weekends: true,

            events: [
                {
                    title: primaryAsset,
                    start:  release_Date,
                    end: release_Date
                }
            ]
          });
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please create event array first then pass into full calender like

```
var evt = [
    {
        title  : 'event1',
        start  : '2014-01-01'
    },
    {
        title  : 'event2',
        start  : '2014-01-05',
        end    : '2014-01-07'
    },
    {
        title  : 'event3',
        start  : '2014-01-09T12:30:00',
        allDay : false 
    }
];
```

then add into full calender

```
 $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
        },
        editable: true,
        weekMode: 'liquid',
        weekends: true,

        events: evt
      });
```

Comment: Nice implementation sir. Sir, how can I do this dynamically? I mean, without enumerating the events one by one in the variable. Using for loop i guess.

Answer (score 0):

This my script to get json data from php file. thats may works for you.

```
<script>
$('#calendar').fullCalendar(
{
    header: {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
    },
    editable: true,
    events:
    {   // Render the events in the calendar
        url: 'calendarData.php', // Get the URL of the json feed
        error: function() 
        {
            alert('There Was An Error While Fetching Events Or The Events Are Not Found!');
        }
    }
});
</script>
```

calendarData.php

```
$return_array = array();
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sth)) 
        {
            $event_array = array();
            $event_array['id'] = $row['e_id'];
            $date_start = $row['e_date_start'];
            $date_end   = $row['e_date_end'];
                $date_start = explode(" ",$date_start);
                $date_end   = explode(" ", $date_end);
                $date_start[0] = str_replace('-' , '/' , trim($date_start[0]));
                $date_end[0] = str_replace('-' , '/' , trim($date_end[0]));
                //Event Title Structure
            if($row['e_title'] != "")
            {
                $event_array['title'] = $row['e_title'];
                    //Start Date Structure
                    if($date_start[0] != "0000/00/00" && $date_start[1] != "00:00:00")
                    {

                        $event_array['start'] = date(DATE_ISO8601, strtotime($date_start[0]." ".$date_start[1]));
                    }

                    //End Date Structure
                    if($date_end[0] != "0000/00/00" && $date_end[1] != "00:00:00")
                    {

                        $event_array['end'] = date(DATE_ISO8601, strtotime($date_end[0]." ".$date_end[1]));
                    }

                    //All Day Event Structure
                    if($row['e_allday'] == '1')
                    {
                        $event_array['allDay'] = true;

                    }
                    elseif($row['e_allday'] == '0') 
                    {
                        $event_array['allDay'] = false;
                    }

                array_push($return_array, $event_array);
            }
        }
        echo json_encode($return_array);
```

Comment: Can you use events.push instead of listing the events in calendarData.php? Because i really want to display my data from the for loop that contains my events.

Comment: $return_array = array();
//[make loop and store data in $return_array]
array_push($return_array, $event_array);
//[after loop complete]
echo json_encode($return_array);

Comment: you should not loop on $('#calendar').fullCalendar({});
just try to get events from json  
events:
{
    url: 'calendarData.php'
}

Answer (score 0):

Here are the steps that I took, which worked pretty slick: 
1. Load the calendar, using the basic code in fullCalendar documentation:

```
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
    // page is now ready, initialize the calendar...
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    // put your options and callbacks here
    })
    });
    </script>
```

2. make sure you can actually pull in the data from your array (it doesn't need to be in the calendar yet, just load it onto the page to verify that it works). Something like this should do it: (note, I have not tested this code, but it is close. May need to be tweeked though)

   ```
   if ( have_posts() ) :
     //start a while statement
     while ( have_posts() ) :
       the_post();
       $content_types = get_the_terms( $post_id, $taxonomy_categories );
       $tag_link = get_field('tag_link');
       $tag_host = parse_url($tag_link);
       $tag_page = $tag_host['scheme'] . '://' . $tag_host['host'];

       echo the_title();
       echo the_field('date');
     endwhile;
   endif;
   ```
3. add static array, to test if the array elements will be displayed on the calendar. Use code from fullCalendar documentation:

   ```
   $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
   events: [
     {
         title  : 'event1',
       start  : '2010-01-01'
     },
     {
       title  : 'event2',
       start  : '2010-01-05',
       end    : '2010-01-07'
     },
     {
       title  : 'event3',
       start  : '2010-01-09T12:30:00',
       allDay : false // will make the time show
     }
   ]
   });
   ```
4. Finally, once everything to this point is working, replace the static data with dynamic data. You can do this by wrapping it with a loop, and getting the necessary fields through php. Here is the code that I used:

   ```
   <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
    // page is now ready, initialize the calendar...
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    // put your options and callbacks here
      events: [
        //start if
        <?php
        if ( have_posts() ) :
          //start a while statement
          while ( have_posts() ) :
            the_post();
            $content_types = get_the_terms( $post_id, $taxonomy_categories );
            $tag_link = get_field('tag_link');
            $tag_host = parse_url($tag_link);
            $tag_page = $tag_host['scheme'] . '://' . $tag_host['host'];
           ?>
           {
             title  : '<?php the_title();?>',
             start  : '<?php the_field('date');?>'

             //only need one item in the array, because with the while loop, this will repeat until all the posts are added.

           },
               <?php
               endwhile;
               endif;
               ?>
           ]
       })

   });
   ```